# How can I disable Recycle Bin globally in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

In Windows Vista or 7 I can go to group policy editor (gpedit.msc) then User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer and enable there the "Do not move deleted files to the Recycle Bin" setting.

However, in Windows 8.1 the Windows Explorer category no longer seem to exists under group policy editor – at least not the way it was before.

Therefore, is there any (other) way to disable the Recycle Bin globally ? (i.e. *not* per-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section you are looking for is now named "File Explorer", and it contains that option.

[image: GP Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The Do not move deleted files to the Recycle Bin policy sets the `NoRecycleFiles` Value Name, a `REG_DWORD` data type,
at `HKEY_USERS\<UserSid>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` to 1.

Comment: Well, previously I searched for this Value Name (and didn't found it) expecting it to be 0, but now I realize that this registry entry is either to be manually created, or is automatically created after explicitly specify the Enable or Disable under that group policy setting – so the info proved to be useful as well.